# Error when running program through virtual machine

Tags: python, directory, virtual-machine

We have written a python script to run within a forced speech alignment program. The speech alignment program was written with python but is run as an image through a Virtual Machine. The script instructs the program to align all of the files in a designated folder that is shared between the Virtual Machine and the computer's hard drive.

The command line of the VM image points to the shared folder where the files and the python script are located. It successfully opens the python script but once we try to open the directory specified in the script it says that there is no such file found. Would this have anything to do with the fact that it is being run in the virtual machine?

Here is the part of the script that points to the directory:

```
import sys
import os

def main():

    direct=r'/Desktop/Shared/sf_VM_Shared/faseAlign/F3'

    for file in os.listdir(direct):
```

and here is the error message:

```
ubuntu@BCE:~/Desktop/Shared/sf_VM_Shared/faseAlign/F3$ python3 FASE.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FASE.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "FASE.py", line 9, in main
    for file in os.listdir(direct):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop/Shared/sf_VM_Shared/faseAlign/F3'
```